# MultiSite Creation in Drupal

Tags: 7, multi-sites

Its drupal 7 wesite.

suppose:I have a domain . url --> www.pqs.com

---

I need a multisite with this url. I have two sections in this site one is **Civil construction** and another is **Electromechanical** .

When i load the URL ,there will be a landing page loaded .This landing page contains two links, one is **Civil construction** and another is **Electromechanical** .

so the url for each section maybe ***www.pqs.com/civil***    &  ***www.pqs.com/electromech***.
The design layout ,contents and menus for both sections are different.

Is it really a multisite?   I don't want subdomains for this.

How can i accomplish this in drupal 7 by a professional manner?

Please suggest me an effective method.

-------------------------------My Edits---------------------------------------

i found multisite_wizard and installed in my test server.
Remark: i installed the site in my test server *pqs.com/prosq/* . **prosq** is the drupal installed folder.
In Sites.php file i entered the following line:

`$sites = array('pqs.com/prosqa/Civil'; => 'Civil','pqs.com/prosqa/MEP'; => 'MEP' );`

When i configuring the module i am stuck on the following step:
 **Create sites folders inside sites/ folder** 
Also i saw this message:

> Hint: the folders names should be the same as values of domain-folder
>   array in the site.php file Folders to be created:
>   pqs.com/prosqa/Civil,pqs.com/prosq/MEP

I created Civil,MEP in sites folder and refresh the config page.But i still saw the same.Please help me.

Comment: i found multisite_wizard and installed in my test server.In 
Sites.php file i entered the following line:

$sites = array('http://pqs.com/prosqa/Civil' => 'Civil','http://pqs.com/prosqa/MEP' => 'MEP' );

When i configuring the module i am stuck on the following step:
Create sites folders inside sites/ folder
Hint: the folders names should be the same as values of domain-folder array in the site.php file
Folders to be created: http://pqs.com/prosqa/Civil,http://pqs.com/prosq/MEP
I created Civil,MEP in sites folder.But it is nor detecting.